# Notify in derived class when a property has changed in the base class

Tags: c#, class, derived-class, base-class

I want to execute some code on derived Form whenever a specific property changes in the base Form.

A form implements some common stuff on forms (skining, etc)

Example:

```
abstract class A
{
    private bool _value;

    public abstract void Execute();

    public A()
    {
        _value = false;
    }

    public bool Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;

            if (value)
            {
                Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public B()
    {

    }

    public override void Excute()
    {
        // Do some stuff here
    }
}
```

I have been dealing with abstract methods, but I cannot figure how to solve it.

If I declare A as abstract I cannot open B in the designer.

In fact, the real code is a bit more complex, because I have an A base class (a form with the common functions) and B, C, D wich are derived forms more specific: B with button navitagion, C for special forms, etc. So when I create a form in my application, I must inherit from B, or C, ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that properties are not supposed to have side-effects, so maybe a method is a better approach here.

Comment: You could create an event OnValueChanged or whatever in the base class so that the derived class or any other class could subscribe to. Sorry I cannot post some code, I'm typing on the Android app.

Comment: Or you could declare an abstract method in your base class and call it directly. Any derived class will have to implement it using whatever code the derived class needs executed.

Comment: Mihai's 2nd comment would be great if your base class was an abstract class - but it is not.  The best you can do is either an event like he suggested or a virtual method which is called in the base class which the derived class may override.  

It violates OOP principles to some extent to have an instantiatable base class which depends in any way on its derived class - hence it is not allowed to force it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was solved, but I have another problem. Class A is a Form, wich will implement some basic features. B is another form that inherits A. The problem is that, althought it works with Mihai's solution, now I cannot open in designer B form because inherits from an abstract class. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the property as virtual in your base class, then override it in your derived class, calling your `Foo` method from the derived class's setter. Due to polymorphism, your derived property will always be accessed, even when your object is referenced as a base class instance.

```
class A
{
    public virtual bool Value { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
    public override bool Value
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.Value != value)
            {
                base.Value = value;
                Foo();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Foo()
    {
        // code I want to run when base class property changes
    }
}
```